# Getting data from source DB through to the SQL service broker

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

My SQL Server database relies on data in a tertiary SQL Server database. I currently use SSIS or regular SPs on source DB to refresh everything in my DB but of course this is clunky.

I can setup a Queue and stored procedures on my DB to get the message once its in my Queue but... how do i recognize when this should happen?

How do i recognize inserts, Updates and deletions in the source DB tables?

Comment: Can you  elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your requirement is. Sounds like you just want to know when something was Inserted, Updated, or Deleted (DML operation) and based on one of those operations, put some data into a Service Broker Queue.

You can use [DML Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) or Asynchronous Triggers. Take a look at the following example for async triggers:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/asynchronous-triggers-using-sql-broker/

Another option is to use [CDC or Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875(v=sql.130).aspx).